# How can I create defect and attach it to defect suite via Rally API (java)?

Tags: java, rally, suite

How can I create defect and attach it to defect suite via Rally API (java)?
Can you add an example?

Thanks Eyal

Comment: I think your question is too broad.  Give a more specific example, tell your story.

Also, you should not need to care which language the example is given.  Dropping that requirement will get you more answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a java example that queries on an existing defect suite, creates a new defects, adds the defect suite to the new defect's DefectSuites collection and updates the defect:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class addDefectToSuite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@company.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
            String projectRef = "/project/12352608219";      
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129"; 
            String applicationName = "Create defect, add to a defectsuite";


        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   

        QueryRequest defectSuiteRequest = new QueryRequest("DefectSuite");
        defectSuiteRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name", "Defects"));
        defectSuiteRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        defectSuiteRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "DS1"));
        QueryResponse defectSuiteQueryResponse = restApi.query(defectSuiteRequest);
        JsonObject defectSuiteJsonObject = defectSuiteQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println("defectSuiteJsonObject" + defectSuiteJsonObject);
        String defectSuiteRef = defectSuiteJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString(); 
        int numberOfDefects = defectSuiteJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Defects").get("Count").getAsInt();
        System.out.println(defectSuiteJsonObject.get("Name") + " ref: " + defectSuiteRef + "number of defects: " + numberOfDefects + " " + defectSuiteJsonObject.get("Defects"));


        try {
            JsonObject defect = new JsonObject();
            defect.addProperty("Name", "bad defect 668");

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("defect", defect);
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
            if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                JsonObject defectJsonObject = createResponse.getObject();
                String defectRef = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", defectRef));  
                JsonObject defectSuitesOfThisDefect = (JsonObject) defectJsonObject.get("DefectSuites");
                int numberOfSuites = defectSuitesOfThisDefect.get("Count").getAsInt();
                System.out.println("number of defect suites this defect is part of: " + numberOfSuites);
                QueryRequest defectSuitesOfThisDefectRequest = new QueryRequest(defectSuitesOfThisDefect);
                JsonArray suites = restApi.query(defectSuitesOfThisDefectRequest).getResults();
                System.out.println("suites: " + suites);
                suites.add(defectSuiteJsonObject);
                System.out.println("suites after add: " + suites);
                //Update defect: add to defectsutites collection
                JsonObject defectUpdate = new JsonObject();
                defectUpdate.add("DefectSuites", suites);
                UpdateRequest updateDefectRequest = new UpdateRequest(defectRef,defectUpdate);
                UpdateResponse updateResponse = restApi.update(updateDefectRequest);
                if (updateResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully updated defect: " + defectJsonObject.get("FormattedID"));
                }
                else {
                    String[] updateErrors;
                    updateErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    for (int i=0; i<updateErrors.length;i++) {
                        System.out.println(updateErrors[i]);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }   

    } 
}
```

Code is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/addDefectToSuite.java).